# MSSQL SERVER with Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

groupBY doesn’t work. I got error:

```
General error: 20018 Column 'XXXXXXXXXX' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

This is my code:

```
DB::table('TABLE')->groupBy('COLUMN')->get();
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The column(s) you are not grouping by either need to be an aggregate (min, max, sum, etc) or be part of the group by.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. `DB::table('TABLE')->get()->groupBy('COLUMN');`
I should put get() before groupBy()

Comment: And this is select all whole table in memory in group in memory.